# Why field CPS is mandatory in EDIFACT?

Tags: edi, edifact

According to the specification of EDIFACT, CPS is mandatory in DESADV. 
https://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/D97A/CPS_.htm
But we don't have any data to send in CPS segment.
Can we construct a DESADV message, which contains LIN and QTY segments in segment group #15 without the CPS segment? 
https://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/D97A/DESADV.htm#SG15

Comment: According to D.97A standard, CPS is optional with a max uses of 1 and 9999 on the loop.

Comment: the only thing mandatory about a CPS segment is the hierarchical id. So if you have only one package, you just add a single CPS segment with hierarchical ID 1 and add your line segments under that.

Answer (score 1):

`CPS` is the trigger segment indicating the start of `SG10`. `SG15` is a child of `SG10` so while it's valid to construct a `DESADV` without any `CPS` segments, it would not be possible to include any `LIN` segments or any other detail information in that message.

You can see this in the Message Structure at the bottom of the page you linked to earlier: https://www.stylusstudio.com/edifact/D97A/DESADV.htm#part4.3

`CPS` indicates packing structure, with the top level covering the entire shipment, so the simplest structure contains a single `CPS` with all of the `LIN` (etc) below that.